# Tem como simplificar minha estrutura? se sim como

Tags: javascript, funções

Ja consegui resolver essa questao mais queria saber se consigo simplificar ela pois estou no meio de aprendizado e busco diversas formas de fazer a mesma coisa pra poder fixa bem na mente. a questao e a seguinte.

Um estacionamento deseja automatizar a cobrança de mensalistas.

Se o motorista realizou até 20 entradas, ele deve pagar R$ 10,00 por entrada realizada.

Da vigésima primeira entrada em diante, cada entrada custa R$ 5,00 ao cliente.

```
//array que recebe as placas dos veiculos

var placas = [
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'
 ]
 
//aqui calcula quantas vezes essa mesma placa entrou no estacionamento

 function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa){

    var entradas = 0

    for(var i = 0;i < placas.length; i++) {

       if (placas[i] == placa){

           entradas++

       }

    }

    return entradas

 }

//aqui calcula o valor que o dono do carro deve pagar, E aqui que queria simplificar o código

 function calcularValorDevido(placa){

   var valorDevido = calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa)

    if (valorDevido < 21){

       return valorDevido = valorDevido*10

    } else{

       return valorDevido = ((valorDevido-20)*5) + (20*10)

    }

}

 console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas("ORO-7142"))

 console.log(calcularValorDevido("ORO-7142"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende da sua definição de "simplificar", o que é simples para mim pode não ser simples para você, aqui está a minha solução para o seu problema que eu acredito ser "simples".

Você vai precisar de métodos como [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) que retorna o mínimo entre 2 ou mais elementos passados como parâmetro, que no seu caso caso eu usei com `(20, entrada)`, ou seja se o número de entradas for maior que 20, ele irá retornar 20, se não retorna o número de entradas.

Também usei o método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que filtra um array em base a função passada como parâmetro e retorna um novo array com todos os elementos que passaram no teste, que neste caso eu usei para criar um novo array com todos os elementos que tem a mesma placa e então eu pego simplesmente o `length` deste novo array que corresponde ao número de entradas.

Observações:

O array `placas` pode não existir, então neste caso pode-se adicionar um operador ternario para evitar erros, por exemplo `placas.filter` vai ter dar erro se `placas` não existir pois ele irá tentar aplicar o método `filter` em um valor que não existe, então ficaria assim com o operador `placas?.filter` neste caso se o array não existir ele irá retornar `null` e por isso adicionamos um controle ao final da expressão `?? 0` ou seja se o valor a esquerda o filter por algum motivo retornar `null`, então ele usa 0 como valor default.

```js
var placas = [
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'
 ];

 function calcDivida(placa){
    // Procura o número de ocorrencias desta mesma placa dentro ao array
    const entrada =  placas?.filter(p => p === placa).length ?? 0;

    // Controlamos se houveram entradas adicionais usando o operador ternario, basicamente um if/else em uma linha como podes ver
    const entradasAdicionais = entrada < 21 ? 0 : entrada - 20;
    
    // O valor inicial é dado do minimo entre 20 e o número de entradas multiplicado por 10
    const valorInicial = Math.min(20, entrada) * 10;
    
    // O valor adicional é o valor salvado antes multiplicado por 5
    const valorAdicional = entradasAdicionais * 5;
    
    // retornamos a soma de ambos
    return valorInicial + valorAdicional;
 }
 
 console.log(calcDivida('RXB-2525')); // 170 
 console.log(calcDivida('AKX-3333')); // 270
```

Comment: acho que me coloquei errado na questao simplificar, mais era isso mesmo outras formas para fazer a mesma coisa, me ajudou muito tem coisas que preciso me aprofundar mais, e a maneira que você respondeu me mostrou outra maneira de resolver o problema e ate mais bonito de se ver kkkk XD.